# How to get Skype for Business and Teams working

Tags: microsoft-office-365, skype-for-business-online

Users in our company have been ignoring SfB and using their own choice of software to get features missing from SfB. This has meant that we have users using different software (HipChat, Stride, Slack and SfB) and we are now looking to get all users use Teams instead, company wide.

To achieve this we have started rolling out Teams to the bigger teams as a proof of concept to ensure that it fulfills everyone's needs.

The issue is that the users who are not using Teams are only using SfB and our Teams users need to run both applications. I understand it is possible to communicate with SfB users from Teams, but I am struggling to find anything that shows me how to do it.

Is it possible or have I misunderstood? If it is, how do I configure it?

**What I am seeing... or not as the case maybe**

I see the status of SfB users in Teams, but if I message one of them they only receive an email about a message being sent to them in Teams. Since they don't have access to Teams they cannot respond.

If a SfB user messages me, I see the message in SfB if running, or I get an email to say I missed their message.

Comment: Maybe you could describe the problems you're having. I'm having no issues communicating between Teams and SfB users.

Comment: I've added precisely what the issue is. Teams users cannot send messages to SfB users and SfB users can message Teams users but the messages are within SfB still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have sorted my issue, which I am documenting here in case others need it.

Firstly I needed to download and install the [SkypeOnlineConnector Powershell Module](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39366).

Then run the following commands in Powershell to open a new PS Session:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector
$socSession = New-CsOnlineSession
Import-PSSession $socSession
```

My problem was that the tenant was set to Islands, and every user was inheriting that setting, effectively putting them all into Islands mode, so Teams went to Teams and SfB went to SfB. I needed to run this command for each user setting the PolicyName to either `SfbOnly` or `UpgradeToTeams` as required:

```
Grant-CsTeamsUpgradePolicy -PolicyName $policy -Identity $userPrincipalName
```

`SfbOnly` configures the user to only have SkypeForBusiness access so messages to/from a Teams user are sent to SfB.

`UpgradeToTeams` configures a user to have Teams only, so their messages only go to/from Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 0):

If your organization completed upgrate to teams this might not be allowed:

```
TeamsUpgradePolicy cannot be set because Microsoft has already upgraded this organization.
```